# How to understand the distribution probability of the forecast trend by Facebook Prophet?

Tags: time-series, prediction, facebook-prophet

I am trying to get understand the distribution of the forecast trends by Facebook Prophet. I know it has uncertainty interval for the forecast with the specified period, but I do not really know how does the uncertainty interval distribute and is it possible to calculate the probability for a specified interval?

I have read the paper about Prophet and know the forecast trend can be influenced by adjusting the parameters including `changepoint_prior_scale`, `interval_width`, `mcmc_samples`. Because I am not really familiar with statistics, for my understanding, the forecast value should be distributed in a range and their total probability is 1 like a standard normal distribution.

I want to know for the specified range of the forecast value by Prophet, can I know its probability? For example, if the Prophet model gives me the forecast for the population will increase in three months and the upper bound is 10000 and lower bound 1000, can I know the probability which the size of the population is located between 2000 and 8000 in three months?

Answer (score 1):

You can control the probability range with the [`interval_width`](https://facebook.github.io/prophet/docs/uncertainty_intervals.html#uncertainty-in-the-trend). If you know the confidence that you desire, modify it accordingly:

```
forecast = Prophet(interval_width=0.80).fit(df).predict(future)
```